# Delay in Plotting Data from a Serial Port using Control.Invoke and Delegates

Tags: c#, serial-port, zedgraph

I am reading data values from a serial port and plotting the data in realtime on a zedgraph control using invoke and delegate. I would like to click a disconnect button that will stop the plotting and when a connect button is pressed, the plotting will resume. My problem is when I reconnect, the plotting will not be displayed at 1 point per second. There will be unexpected behavior that sometimes includes a delay that will not plot for 2 seconds and the next second it will plot 2 points at the same time. Sometimes it will not plot for 3 seconds and the next second, it will plot 3 points at the same time and sometimes it will work fine plotting 1 point per second. Sometimes it will plot twice or three times per second. This problem occurs only when I disconnect and then reconnect. My GUI response also begins to get worse with every time I disconnect and reconnect until finally not responding.

When I click disconnect, I clear the zedgraph but don't close the serial port. When I re-click connect again, the serial port will begin sending data again and continue to plot, calling control.invoke every time a new data point is plotted onto the zedgraph. Is the problem that I am calling invoke too many times and how would I get around this? I need to plot in realtime, so each time I receive a data point, plot it on the zedgraph right away.

Here is how I connect to the serial port:

```
private void btnConnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curveUSB = myPaneUSB.AddCurve("Load", listUSB, Color.Black, SymbolType.Circle);
        isConnected = true;

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        txtStartTime.Text = startTime.ToString();
        sw.Start();
        createCSVFile(startTime);

        try
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {

                serialPort1.PortName = cmbPort.Items[cmbPort.SelectedIndex].ToString();


                //Other Serial Port Property
                serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
                serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                //Open our serial port
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }



        Thread.Sleep(100); //Always sleep before reading
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceivedHandler);

        // Save the beginning time for reference
        tickStart = Environment.TickCount;  //used the calculate the time 
        setGraphAxis(myPaneUSB, zgControlUSB);
        //Disable Connect button
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        //Enable Disconnect button
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;        
    }
```

Invoke and serialPort1_DataReceivedHandler:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isConnected == true)
        {
            txtUSBLoad.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {

                strRawData = serialPort1.ReadLine();

                txtUSBLoad.Text = strRawData + loadUnit;
                Display_Data(strRawData, curveUSB, listUSB, zgControlUSB);


            }));
        }
    }
```

Display_Data function to display the plot:

```
private void Display_Data(String data, LineItem curve, IPointListEdit list, ZedGraphControl zgControl) 
    {

        ts = sw.Elapsed;
        tsBT = swBT.Elapsed;
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",tsBT.Hours, tsBT.Minutes, tsBT.Seconds);
        elapsedTimeBT = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", tsBT.Hours, tsBT.Minutes, tsBT.Seconds);
        txtElapsedTime.Text = elapsedTime;
        txtBTElapsedTime.Text = elapsedTimeBT;


        if (zgControl.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)                    //Make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve
            return;
        curve = zgControl.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;            //Get the first CurveItem in the graph
        if (curve == null)
            return;
        list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;                                  //Get the PointPairList
        if (list == null)                                                       //If this is null, it means the reference at curve.Points does not
            return;                                                             //support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it
        time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;             //Time is measured in seconds
                                             //Get current time        
        now = DateTime.Now;
        timestamp = now.ToOADate();
        list.Add(timestamp, Convert.ToDouble(data)); 
        if(fileWriter.BaseStream != null){  //If fileWriter is open, then write to file, else don't write
            fileWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}", now) + "," + data);   //writes the timestamp and data to the CSV file
        }
        if (Convert.ToDouble(data) > tempLoad)  //Checks if the current load is the maximum load
        {
            tempLoad = Convert.ToDouble(data);
            txtMaxLoad.Text = tempLoad.ToString() + " " + loadUnit;
            txtBTMaxLoad.Text = tempLoad.ToString() + " " + loadUnit;
        }
        //if ((Convert.ToDouble(data) > dblThreshold) && (emailAlerts == true)) { 
        if ((Convert.ToDouble(data) > 50) && (emailAlerts == true))
        { 
            sendEmail(Convert.ToDouble(data));
        }

        XDate dateTime = curve[0].X;                                   

        zgControl.AxisChange();                                          //changes the x-axis  
        zgControl.Invalidate();                                          //Force a redraw
    }
```

Disconnect button:

```
 private void btnDisconnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        zgControlUSB.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
        if (fileWriter != null)
        {
            fileWriter.Close(); 
        }
        isConnected = false;
        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
        txtUSBLoad.Text = initText;
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        txtEndTime.Text = endTime.ToString();   //displays the time stamp when the plotting stops
        sw.Stop();  //stops the stop watch 

    }
```

When I disconnect, I do not close the serial port because the problem is worse when I do and I read that it is not good to  always close and reopen a serial port. Instead, I used an isConnected flag to start and stop plotting.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Calling txtUSBLoad.Invoke() will switch processing onto the GUI thread (the same thread that is used to handle user input and draw the controls).  By putting all the processing *inside* the call to Invoke() you are effectively swamping the GUI thread.

If your serial updates are frequent enough this will result in delayed interactions/re-drawing  of the GUI.

You have a few options here, the first thing is to keep all the processing in the thread that receives the messages from the serial port.  Look at all the visual controls that you are updating and the determine what data they need to be updated and process as much of that *before* calling Invoke().  Create a class to hold the data.

This might be too slow which will mean that you'll have a backlog of serial data building up which you can't process in time.  If so, you can conflate the incoming data if you're ok with losing updates.  You'll have to see if this applies to your situation.

If you want to try and parallelise the processing of the incoming data look into [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example of how to create a processing pipeline for the data.